Ionic Styles are not rendered for the PWA app
Update:  After troubleshooting it for 2 days, reinstalls, cleaning cache - I have finally managed to get the same error for "ionic serve" and "http-server ./www".  The error is:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
This error shows up regardless of the page I'm starting from. For example, if I am already logged in its the first tab and if I am not logged in, its the login page. For the "ionic serve" the page renders fine but shows the error with that page name in the console.  For "http-server ./www" - the Ionic CSS doesn't render (custom css still does) and error message is the same.
Original Problems Statement
I am building a PWA app with standalone components.  Ionic Serve renders everything accurately.  However, when I build it as a PWA, it renders the custom css in global.scss but nothing from the core global.scss or theme/variables.scss.  Spent more than 20 hours trying to trouble shoot it.  Even tried getting help from AI but no success.   I can confirm that all the icons and files are where they are supposed to be.  Below is my code:
//main.ts

import { enableProdMode, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, provideRouter, withPreloading, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicRouteStrategy, provideIonicAngular } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import 'intl-relative-time-format';
import { provideServiceWorker } from '@angular/service-worker';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    DecimalPipe,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }, 
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideIonicAngular(),
    provideRouter(routes, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules)), 
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }, 
    provideServiceWorker('ngsw-worker.js', {
            enabled: !isDevMode(),
            registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
      }), 

  ],
})


<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>App</title>

  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes"/>
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>

    <link rel="icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.png">
  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
  <link rel="manifest" href="assets/manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>

</html>

Manifest File:
{
  "name": "app",
  "short_name": "app",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    }
  ]
}


angular.json file
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
          "styleext": "scss",
          "standalone": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": ["src/global.scss", "src/theme/variables.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
            "optimization": {
              "styles": false
            },
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "app:build:development"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": ["src/global.scss", "src/theme/variables.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.html"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": ["@ionic/angular-toolkit"]
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:application": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    },
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:library": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    }
  }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^18.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^6.1.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^6.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^6.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^6.0.1",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^6.0.2",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^6.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.5",
    "@capacitor/text-zoom": "^6.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^8.3.0",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.3.0",
    "@ngx-maintenance/ng2-search-filter": "^1.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "intl-relative-time-format": "^1.0.7",
    "ionic8-calendar": "^1.0.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.2.1",
    "ngx-clarity": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "swiper": "^11.1.14",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^18.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.5.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^48.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "5.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}

ngsw-config.json file
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.csr.html",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/**/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

global.scss file:
/*
 * App Global CSS
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Put style rules here that you want to apply globally. These styles are for
 * the entire app and not just one component. Additionally, this file can be
 * used as an entry point to import other CSS/Sass files to be included in the
 * output CSS.
 * For more information on global stylesheets, visit the documentation:
 * https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/global-stylesheets
 */

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
@import "@ionic/angular/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
@import "@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/structure.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/typography.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/display.css";

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
@import "@ionic/angular/css/padding.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css";

/**
 * Ionic Dark Mode
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 * For more info, please see:
 * https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode
 */

/* @import "@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.always.css"; */
/* @import "@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.class.css"; */
@import '@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.system.css';

@import 'swiper/css';

.circleBase {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  .type1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #070a57 0%, #0d6efd 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(98, 140, 255, 0.5);
    top: -50px;
    left: -50px;
    text-align: right;
  }

  
  .type2 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background:#070a57;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .circle1 {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .circle2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    left: -20px;
  }
  
  .error {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
  }

 .itemDesign {
  border: 1px solid var(--ion-color-dark);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: none;
}

 .buttonDesign {
    width: 250px;
  }

.front-header {
      height: 25vh;
      width: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--ion-color-primary) 10%, var(--ion-color-primary) 100%);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 10px var(--ion-color-light);
      border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
      margin-left: -14vh;
      margin-top: -160px;
}

.welcomeMessage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 50px;
 p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
}

.signup {
    margin-top: 0vh;
    font-size: 1.0rem;
  }
  
.ion-col {
    ion-note {
      font-size: 0.85rem;
    }
}

.clearbackground {
  background: none;
}

.gradientbackground {
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #070a57 0%, #0d6efd 100%);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(98, 140, 255, 0.5);
}


.monthview-current{
 background-color: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}
.monthview-primary-with-event {
            background-color:  var(--ion-color-light) !important;
            color: dark;
 }

.monthview-selected {
            background-color: var(--ion-color-secondary) !important;
            color: white;
        }

.monthview-primary-with-event-appointment {
            background-color:  var(--ion-color-success) !important;
            color: white;
 } 


.calendar-event-inner{
   background-color:  var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
   color: white;
}

.appointment { 

 background-color:  var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
   color: white;
}

ion-radio::part(container) {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ion-radio::part(mark) {
  background: none;
  transition: none;
  transform: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

ion-radio.radio-checked::part(container) {
  background: var(--ion-color-primary);
  border-color: transparent;
}

ion-radio.radio-checked::part(mark) {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;

  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;

  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

ion-title {
  text-align: center;
}

text-label-wrap {
max-width:120px; 
word-wrap:break-word;
}

text-any-wrap {
word-wrap:break-word;
}

ion-datetime {
    --background: rgb(250,245,255);
    --background-rgb: 250,245,255;
    --wheel-highlight-background: rgb(250,245,255);
    --wheel-highlight-border-radius: 48px;
    --wheel-fade-background-rgb: 13, 110, 253;
}
  
.ion-datetime::part(wheel-item) {
    color: rgb(7,10,87);
}
  
.ion-datetime::part(wheel-item active) {
    color: rgb(13, 110, 253);
}

indented-note {
  padding-left: 20px; 
}

custom-popover {
  --width: 90vw;  
}





"styles": ["src/global.scss", "src/theme/variables.scss"], these are then ones you build in you syles.css in build. My question is what do you mean it does not render core global ? do you have other css files that does not render ?

Yes, I have added the screenshots in both cases.  The nice looking one is from Ionic Serve and other one is from ionic build.  I have even commented out my custom css to see if that is not causing an issue.  Even started a new ionic app and copied scss over to test.  No success.

Can you paste the global.scss because it seems your custom css in that file effects but not the one imported, may be you are importing in the wrong way.

@BalkishanDhaker - just added it.  Please see above the images.

I completely removed any custom css and rebuilt it.  It still shows a broken site but renders fine on ionic serve.
